# Copy and paste to the last row of Excel sheet from Notepad

Tags: excel, vba

I was able to copy content from notepad to Excel.

I am running into a problem pasting data below the last filled in row.

Below is part of the code. It pastes the data but when it reaches the next text file, it says object not supported at: `ws.Paste Range("A1:A" & 1LastRow)`

```
Option Explicit

Dim p
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim MyPath As String
Dim strFilename As String
Dim lLastRow As Long
Dim LC As Long
Dim s As Worksheet, t As String
Dim i As Long, K As Long
K = Sheets.Count
Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("First Sheet")
Sheets("First Sheet").Columns(1).NumberFormat = "@"
Sheets("First Sheet").Columns(2).NumberFormat = "@"
Sheets("First Sheet").Columns(3).NumberFormat = "@"

Application.DisplayAlerts = False
Application.EnableEvents = False
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("First Sheet")
lLastRow = ws.UsedRange.Rows(ws.UsedRange.Rows.Count).Row + 1
p = Shell("Notepad.exe " & myfile, vbNormalFocus)
waitTime (2000) 'as an alternative
AppActivate p, False
Application.SendKeys "^a", True 'sends select all command keys
waitTime (500)
Application.SendKeys "^c", True 'sends copy keys
waitTime (500)
ws.activate
ws.Paste Range("A1:A" & 1LastRow)

Loop

Application.DisplayAlerts = False
Application.EnableEvents = False
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
End Sub

Public Function waitTime(ms As Long)
    Application.Wait Now() + (ms / 24 / 60 / 60 / 1000)
End Function
```

New code suggested by Comintern

```
Sub ISINCompilerx2()
Dim handle As Integer
Dim wbDst As Workbook
Dim wsDst As Worksheet
Dim lastRow As Long
Dim MyPath As String
Dim strFilename As String
handle = FreeFile
Set wbDst = ThisWorkbook
Set wsDst = wbDst.Worksheets("First Sheet")
lastRow = wsDst.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row + 1

MyPath = "W:\Product Platforms\ISIN- CUSIP Country of Corporation\August 2018\All Asset Classes\"
strFilename = Dir(MyPath, vbNormal)

Do While strFilename <> ""
    Dim buffer As String
    Open MyPath & strFilename For Input As #handle
    buffer = Input(LOF(handle), handle)  '<-- reads the entire contents of the file to "buffer"
    Close #handle

    With CreateObject("new:{1C3B4210-F441-11CE-B9EA-00AA006B1A69}")
        .SetText buffer
        .PutInClipboard
    End With

    wsDst.Activate
    Range("A1").Select
    Selection.Paste
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    strFilename = Dir()
Loop

End Sub
```

Comment: Looks like a few issues there... what are you trying to do in that line?  You're using syntax SIMILAR (but no tthe same) as ws.Copy Range("A1:B" & i), which in itself is not correct.  YOu would need to define identical ranges for this to work, so a whole sheet onto a smaller range is no bueno.

Comment: Try `Destination:=ws.Range("A" & 1LastRow))`

Comment: Hello Cyril, I am trying to copy what's on notepad to excel. Every part works except the pasting it to excel once everything has been copied in notepad. It works for the first file when i just do ws.Paste Range("A1") but i ofcourse want to do it for 9 files in total so it needs to paste below the last filled row

Comment: @GMalc where should i paste that line?

Comment: Replace line; `ws.Paste Range("A1:A" & 1LastRow)` and see if it works, no guarantee.

Comment: It says compile error:expected expression on :=

Comment: You have a typo `1LastRow` vs `lLastRow`

Comment: Hi Chris, thank you and i corrected the typo but the problem persists.

Comment: You know that Notepad simply opens text files, right? Is there some reason you're using copy and paste instead of simply opening up the file and reading it directly?

Comment: Doing this because we get once every week huge number of CSV files by our IT team. However, a lot of numbers get converted in scientific format so when i copy paste them to notepad and then ultimately to my active workbook, it avoids formatting problems. I want to automate it so it gets done quickly.

Comment: +1 for having `Option Explicit` in your module. -100 for not actually `Dim`ing any of your variables. This code doesn't even begin to compile... Also, scientific formatting is "fixable" by changing the format of a cell in Excel and the width of the column so everything will display. Put a simple 9-digit SSN in a cell in Excel and it will display it in scientific notation until you make the column wider...

Comment: I already dimmed my variables, just did not show that part. I will put that part here.. also when i open the csv file from the zipped folder given to us by IT team, they are already in scientific format and when i change the width, many don't change at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You miss the point of my comment above:

> You know that Notepad simply opens text files, right? Is there some
>   reason you're using copy and paste instead of simply opening up the
>   file and reading it directly?

You'll save yourself a ton of hassle by not trying to "automate" other applications when there are native solutions available and easy to implement.  I don't mean use *Excel* to open a text file (or CSV file) directly, I mean use the built in functionality of VBA to read directly from the files.  Opening a text file in Notepad in order to get the contents onto the clipboard using `SendKeys` is slightly absurd given that you can trivially get the entire contents of a text file into a `String`:

```
Dim handle As Integer
handle = FreeFile

Dim buffer As String
Open myfile For Input As #handle
buffer = Input(LOF(handle), handle)  '<-- reads the entire contents of the file to "buffer"
Close #handle
```

If you need to process it from here, just process the text in the `String`.  If you want to *paste* it somewhere, all you really need to do is send it to the clipboard. If you already have a reference to "Microsoft Forms 2.0 Object Library" (e.g. you have a `UserForm` in the project), you can use this:

```
With New MSForms.DataObject
    .SetText buffer
    .PutInClipboard
End With
```

Or if you don't have a reference, you can late bind it using this CLSID:

```
With CreateObject("new:{1C3B4210-F441-11CE-B9EA-00AA006B1A69}")
    .SetText buffer
    .PutInClipboard
End With
```

Once it's on the clipboard you can paste it where-ever it needs to go.

Comment: Hi Comintern, i have modified my code, please see the edit. It's getting stuck at the paste part and i am sure i am doing it wrong, any thoughts? it says pastespecial method not supported

Comment: @Piccinin Skip the `Activate` and `Select`. You should only need one line of code to paste:  `wsDst.Paste wsDst.Range("A1")`

Comment: Comintern. It's done. Thank you for all of this and bearing with my stupidity!

Comment: @Piccinin Not sure I understand the question. It's text, so the only `PasteSpecial` formats available are going to be `"Text"` and `"Unicode Text"`.

Comment: And if i want to paste it as text, how should i go on about doing it is it just wsDst.Range("A1") PasteSpecial xltext? because right now for some reason, it's not copying in some of the files. Will investigate it more

Comment: @Piccinin `.PasteSpecial Format:="Text"`